# Accessing a parent added via wrap function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I have an input field `fld`. I wrap this field inside a `div` in one part of my code.

```
input.wrap('<div>')
```

In another part of the code I obtain the field 'fld' which is a jQuery object.
`fld.el` contains the input field.

Now, I want the `div` I previously wrapped around this `fld`.
`fld.el.parent()` does not work for me. Nor does `fld.el.parents()`. Tried `fld.el.closest('div')` with no luck.

If I load the input element again via id, I am able to access the parent objects.
`$('#'+fld.id).parent()` works. But I do not want to introduce any ids.
Any way in which I can just make use of the `fld.el` I have and obtain the parent?

Comment: not sure if I can do that as the code is a little complicated. But the whole essence is what I have posted

Comment: can you send your markup and script?

Comment: Would be a bit easier to understand once you post your code.

Comment: Can you tell us, what `fld` and `fld.el` contains?

Answer (score 0):

What's the ".el" in `fld.el.parent()` about? Try `fld.parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but try:

```
parentdivs = fld.el.parents("div:first");
```

OR

```
parentdivs = fld.parents("div:first");
```

This will get your first parent div of an item

Comment: Marc, thanks for the suggestion, but it is not returning the parent that I wrapped. It is working in all other cases except when I use wrap() to add a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code and based on the behavior you're describing, I would guess that `fld.el` is not a jQuery object.

Try:

`$(fld.el).parent();`

If you're 100% certain it is a jQuery object (and the above doesn't work) you should post your code, or at least recreate your issue using [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)